# twist dataframe by rank

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

### Setup

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df

          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
1  0.016545  0.850445  0.817744  0.777962  0.757983
2  0.934829  0.831104  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535
3  0.117642  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702
```

---

I want a dataframe where the columns are ranks and each row is `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']` in rank order.

### Ranks

```
df.rank(1).astype(int)

   A  B  C  D  E
0  2  1  3  5  4
1  1  5  4  3  2
2  5  2  3  4  1
3  2  3  4  5  1
```

---

### Expected Results

```
0  1  2  3  4  5
0  B  A  C  E  D
1  A  E  D  C  B
2  E  B  C  D  A
3  E  A  B  C  D
```

### Further explanation

I want to see each row to show me the column in their rank order.  The first row has `'B'` first because it had the first ranking in that row of the original data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
In [90]: df
Out[90]: 
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
1  0.016545  0.850445  0.817744  0.777962  0.757983
2  0.934829  0.831104  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535
3  0.117642  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702

In [91]: df2 = df.apply(lambda row: df.columns[np.argsort(row)], axis=1)

In [92]: df2
Out[92]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  B  A  C  E  D
1  A  E  D  C  B
2  E  B  C  D  A
3  E  A  B  C  D
```

The new DataFrame has the same column index as `df`, but that can be fixed:

```
In [93]: df2.columns = range(1, 1 + df2.shape[1])

In [94]: df2
Out[94]: 
   1  2  3  4  5
0  B  A  C  E  D
1  A  E  D  C  B
2  E  B  C  D  A
3  E  A  B  C  D
```

---

Here's another way.  This one converts the DataFrame to a numpy array, applies `argsort` on axis 1, uses that to index `df.columns`, and puts the result back into a DataFrame.

```
In [110]: pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.array(df).argsort(axis=1)], columns=range(1, 1 + df.shape[1]))
Out[110]: 
   1  2  3  4  5
0  B  A  C  E  D
1  A  E  D  C  B
2  E  B  C  D  A
3  E  A  B  C  D
```

Comment: I have 3 solutions. You nailed one of them.

Comment: That second one was my best answer.  Awesome job. My last one was to stack, reset index, then pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.

```
In [5]: df1 = df.rank(1).astype(int)

In [6]: df3 = df1.replace({rank: name for rank, name in enumerate(df1.columns, 1)})

In [7]: df3.columns = range(1, 1 + df3.shape[1])

In [8]: df3
Out[8]: 
   1  2  3  4  5
0  B  A  C  E  D
1  A  E  D  C  B
2  E  B  C  D  A
3  B  C  D  E  A
```

Yet another way.

```
In [6]: ranks = df.rank(axis=1).astype(int)-1
In [7]: new_values = df.columns.values.take(ranks)

In [8]: pd.DataFrame(new_values)
Out[8]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  B  A  C  E  D
1  A  E  D  C  B
2  E  B  C  D  A
3  B  C  D  E  A
```

Comment: That's a great one.

Comment: @piRSquared last row of the dataframe has different values in Warren Weckesser's answer. But rest of the rows has same value as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack`, `reset_index`, and `pivot`

```
df.rank(1).astype(int).stack().reset_index() \
  .pivot('level_0', 0, 'level_1').rename_axis(None)
```

[image]

---

***Timing***

[image]